# How do I get my VS Code Plugin to build when I get the 'Cant resolve "fs" or "child_process" ' error?

Tags: json, typescript, build

The line that initializes a SimpleGit object `const git: SimpleGit = simpleGit().clean(CleanOptions.FORCE);` causes an issue with the build of my project that results in the error "Can't resolve 'fs' in /node_modules/@kwsites/file-exists/dist/src"... "Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration" (and then the same error with 'child_process' instead of 'fs').

I am importing simple-git using the last method listed under 'Usage' from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git), and also tried using the other 2 methods, all of which lead to this error.

```js
// Option 3
import { simpleGit, SimpleGit, CleanOptions } from 'simple-git';
const git: SimpleGit = simpleGit().clean(CleanOptions.FORCE);
```

I originally followed this guide to set up the [VS Code Plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-webview-ui-toolkit-samples/tree/main/default/hello-world) which uses esbuild. After spending a day trying to figure this out, I switched to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-webview-ui-toolkit-samples/tree/main/default/hello-world-webpack) version that uses WebPack instead (since there seems to be more help online with WebPack), but was still unable to find a working solution.

The current error when I build is:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@kwsites/file-exists/dist/src/index.js 6:13-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/filepath/hello-world/node_modules/@kwsites/file-exists/dist/src'
resolve 'fs' in '/filepath/hello-world/node_modules/@kwsites/file-exists/dist/src'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /filepath/hello-world/node_modules/@kwsites/file-exists/package.json (relative path: ./dist/src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      /filepath/hello-world/node_modules/@kwsites/file-exists/dist/src/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /filepath/hello-world/node_modules/@kwsites/file-exists/dist/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /filepath/hello-world/node_modules/@kwsites/file-exists/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /filepath/hello-world/node_modules/@kwsites/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /filepath/hello-world/node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /filepath/hello-world/node_modules
        single file module
          using description file: /filepath/hello-world/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/fs)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /filepath/hello-world/node_modules/fs doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /filepath/hello-world/node_modules/fs.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /filepath/hello-world/node_modules/fs.js doesn't exist
 @ ./node_modules/@kwsites/file-exists/dist/index.js 6:9-25
 @ ./node_modules/simple-git/dist/cjs/index.js 261:25-56
 @ ./src/webview/main.ts 14:21-42

webpack 5.75.0 compiled with 2 errors in 21770 ms
    [webpack-cli] Compiler is watching files for updates...
```

The intended outcome is a successful build.

Here are the solutions I have tried (and did not work):
[Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62011612/21995318)
[Cannot find module 'fs'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61426469/21995318)

[Electron: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10681#issuecomment-388057616)
[Require nodejs "child_process" with TypeScript, SystemJS and Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546860/require-nodejs-child-process-with-typescript-systemjs-and-electron)
Here is a solution I did not try (because I didn't understand what was said/wasn't enough info):
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-appium/issues/223#issuecomment-498569080

And a list of places I have looked that did not have a good answer for my application:
[NodeJS - Cannot find module in child_process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943470/nodejs-cannot-find-module-in-child-process)
[Cannot find name 'module'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54608170/cannot-find-name-module?rq=3)

After reading [How to fix cannot find module 'fs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56438479/how-to-fix-cannot-find-module-fs?rq=3) and [Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "fs"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50719619/21995318), it seems like there may be an issue between my understanding of client-side and server-side development (I am not entirely sure if it's my use of simple-git in a WebView application causing these issues).

If anyone has any insight, or additional comments solutions that I haven't tried I would really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Edit: I also am trying to modify files, and the method of importing file system as a variable also results in the same error message:
`var fs = require('fs');`